# How can I have a single column on a column chart using MSCharts (within an Asp.Net application)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts, mschart

I'm using the following code to generate a chart:

```
public ActionResult GenerateChart()
{
    var chart = new Chart();
    chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
    chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High;
    chart.Width = 500;
    chart.Height = 400;

    ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
    area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:c}";

    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

    Series serie = new Series();
    serie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    serie.Points.DataBindXY(data, "Year", data, "Amount");
    chart.Series.Add(serie);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

It's a simple column chart with data for a sum of amount (Y-axis) per year (X-axis).

The **data** variable supplied while testing the code has only 1 item. This item represents year 2015 with an amount of a little bit over 9.000 (no pun intended).

As you can see from the image generated below, despite having data for only 1 year, the chart automatically adds the previous year and the next one.

How can I show only 2015? Or at least hide those points/labels programatically? Why is it adding that information?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample chart generated]

Comment: Web version of [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) seems not to have any properties or methods that can manipulate XAxis or Labels. Perhaps, it is possible to override some rendering related methods to get the desired look. Also, I haven't tried it myself, but you may try to take a look at [web page Chart helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/chart-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-0-with-transparent-background).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the margin on the X axis with

`area.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;`